# how to disable voice input key in android keypad

Tags: android, voice, android-keypad

i need a code to disable/hide the voice input key in android keyboard.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

@tim You can add `android:inputType="text|textVisiblePassword|textMultiLine"` to EditText in your xml. This piece of code hides the voice input but auto-suggestion will be closed at the same time.

Comment: Although a workaround, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "disable/hide the voice input key in android keyboard". If you are writing your own input method (a.k.a., soft keyboard), you can elect not to have the voice input key, but you cannot remove keys from system-supplied or third-party keyboards.

Comment: can't we use onKeyPress, compare the id of voice key in keypad & override its function?

Comment: @tim: There is no `onKeyPress` in Android. AFAIK, voice input is handled directly by the input method, not passed to the activity for processing.